# Vim YouCompleteMe

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vim-plugins

I see that the vim plugin YouCompleteMe is a great autocompletion tool but is there a way to get it to complete not just from a file I am working on but external files as well?

Like, if I go to type `return 0;` but have not typed "return" yet, it doesn't show up as a suggestion. Is there a way to make YCM read other files for the ability to suggest these types of things?

Answer (score 1):

YouCompleteMe only triggers (at least in C/C++) on the insertion of '.' and '->'. This is a design feature as if the plugin triggered on every keypress it would be very sluggish since it works by compilation. You can manually trigger the auto-complete menu by pressing Ctrl-Space as and where you require.